# Graph-Traversal: How do I query for "friends and friends of friends" using Gremlin

Tags: database, graph-databases, gremlin

In my graph database I have Branches and Leaves. Branches can "contain" Leaves and Branches can "contain" Branches.

How, using Gremlin, can I find all leaves for a given branch, that are directly or indirectly related to it?

I got this to work in Cypher:

```
START v=node(1) MATCH v-[:contains*1..2]->i RETURN v,i
```

Where the `*1..2` means "friends and friends of friends".

I thought maybe `LoopV` was the way forward, but I just get an `Exception`:

> Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: String

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following in Gremlin 1.4+.

```
g.v(1).out('contains').loop(1){true}{it.out('contains').count() == 0}
```

This says:

1. Start at vertex with id 1
2. Take the outgoing "contains" edges.
3. Loop over the out('contains') section.
4. Loop "infinitely" (make sure your tree doesn't have loops in it)
5. Emit only those vertices touched that don't have more outgoing 'contains'-edges. (i.e. the leaves)

However, looking at what you wanted from Cypher, it looks like you only want 2 steps. Thus, to do that, simply do:

```
g.v(1).out('contains').loop(1){it.loops < 3}
```

Perhaps I misunderstood your question --- either way, that should give you enough to play with.